# /var/mail Folder Permission (Setup Mail Server with Dovecot)

Tags: debian, dovecot, chmod

I am following a [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin) to setup a mail server and accounts on a Debian 7 OS and they ask  to set up a folder permissions to match this:

```
drwxrwsr-x 3 root vmail 4096 Jan 24 21:23 /var/mail
```

But my server shows it like this:

```
drwxrwsrwt 2 root mail 4096 Oct 30 17:00 /var/mail
```

I was googling about setting up folder permissions but all tutorials show how to do it with number using `chmod` command. How would you translate this letters into numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `chmod 1775 /var/mail`.

Note that you can also change the existing record like this:
`chmod o-wt /var/mail`

Answer (score 3):

Never use MTA's built-in delivery agent. Never.

Use `dovecot-lda` aka `deliver` instead. Then you'll get completely separated MTA and POP/IMAP servers. Local mail storage should be owned by POP/IMAP server. `postfix` invokes `dovecot-lda` that acts with dovecot's config and UID. Otherwise you'll stuck with permissions and will be forced to set wide-open permissions to the mailboxex - like 1775. When LDA moved to the dovecot, you can restrict access to the mailboxes to the 700. The other benefit of the `dovecot-lda` is that only one config-file contains path to the local storage and you'll never be catched when postfix and dovecot points to the different locations. Less obvious but way more signifacant benefits are that you'll get access to the dovecot mail filter `sieve` and autoresponder.

There is no reasons to use built-in LDA.

Comment: Touché! I had problems with authentication which could be solved with permissions and this info from Kondybas helped me. Thanks